# Script for modifying cronjob

Tags: shell-script, scripting, cron

Can you please help me to create a script considering follwoing points.

Step 1:

First stop all existing cronjob (at 5 PM) which are running by using #

Step 2:

After that delete some files

Step 3:

Then again start all existing cronjob (by removing #)

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you instead just stop `cron` while you do your maintenance?  Note that this is not a script writing service and you are expected to show what you tried and where you got stuck.  Doing such a script would be quite easy, but also very pointless.

Comment: Yes I know. But need to do this everyday. that's why, i need a script.

Comment: You can do a script that would stop and restart `cron`.  Not sure what your point is but it sounds like bad planning any way I look at it.  Not running a cron job can have some impact depending on what it does.

Comment: thanks. yes i need a script that would stop and restart cron. Can you help me to share that script

Comment: I think you do not understand how cron works...cron is used to define time for tasks. There is no use is stopping or starting it.

Comment: yes. i know how cron works. i think you haven't understand my query

Comment: by 'stop all existing cron job' you mean kill active running job or just prevent job from running, in fomer case you'll need a scheduler, in latter case a 'stop cron' should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julies simple solution, stopping and restarting the service as script (Debian Linux):

```
#!/bin/sh
service cron stop
...
dowhatyouwant
...
service cron start
```

Or delete the crontab temporary:

```
crontab -l > cronsafe
crontab -r
dowhatyouwant
crontab cronsafe
```

Approach for short interrupts; send a STOP signal to cron and resume with CONT, like

```
killall -STOP cron
dowhatyouwant
killall -CONT cron
```